# How can I update an obect to the value of another object with the same structure?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, setstate

I have two objects:

```
filter: {
   brand: [],
   size: [],
   orderBy: 1,
   page: 1,
   pageSize: 15,
   search: search,
   condition: [],
   gender: [],
   offeredBy: [],
   color: []
};

tmpFilters: {
   brand: [],
   size: [],
   orderBy: 1,
   page: 1,
   pageSize: 15,
   search: search,
   condition: [],
   gender: [],
   offeredBy: [],
   color: []
};
```

My goal is to set the filters to the value of temporary filters. Here is what I have already tried but not working.

```
    let newObj = { ...tmpFilters };
    await setFilter(newObj);
    console.log(filter);
```

When I write out the filter in the console, it says that the value wasn't changed. I have check the other answers but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your state has been changed, but`setState` does not reflect changes immediately. The new value won't be available until the next render cycle.

Comment: ^^ There's no point using `await` on `setFilter`, state setters don't return promises (or indeed anything else useful).